# PHP Where to save OpenSSL encryption key?

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I'm using this php function to encrypt some strings.

```
openssl_encrypt();
```

To generate the encryption key I use

```
$encryption_key = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32);
```

I also know that this encryption key should be stored somewhere.
The problem is that I don't want to store it in my database, because it could be accessible for hackers.
Where could I also store my keys safely?


P.S. It makes any sense to store encrypted data and used keys in the same database

Comment: Your database shouldn't be 'hacker accessible'. You should be able to trust it as you do any other storage location.  Nothing is fully hacker-proof.

Comment: @rmirabelle It make no sense to store encrypted data and used keys in the same database

Comment: I store the key itself hardcoded into a PHP file. This at least puts the key and the encrypted values in separate places, which is a good strategy as you suggest.

Comment: @rmirabelle Could you show an example, please?

Comment: I smell an XY-Problem. Can you edit your question and make clear what you try to achieve by the encryption? What data are you hiding from whom? As it is currently written, this is too broad to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example encryption class I created in PHP. The encryption key is stored in this class, which can then be used to decrypt encrypted DB values.  Hope this helps.

```
/**
 * Provides basic encryption and decryption of strings and objects.
 * Reasonable protection is provided, but you are still responsible
 * for sanitizing the source strings or objects prior to use.
 */

class Encrypter {

    /**
     * This is the global encryption key for the site.
     * The longer you make this key, the more secure the encryption
     */
    const MASTER_KEY = 'my_amazing_key_of_death';

    private $key;
    private $cipher;
    private $mode;
    private $iv;
    private $iv_size;
    private $key_size;
    private $block_size;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->key          = self::MASTER_KEY
        $this->cipher       = MCRYPT_BLOWFISH;
        $this->mode         = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
        $this->block_size   = mcrypt_get_block_size($this->cipher);
        $this->iv_size      = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->cipher, $this->mode);
        $this->key_size     = mcrypt_get_key_size($this->cipher, $this->mode);
        $this->iv           = mcrypt_create_iv($this->iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);

        /**
         * if the calculated keysize is shorter than
         * they key provided, trim the provided key
         * to match its length
         */
        if (strlen($this->key) > $this->key_size) {
            $this->key = substr($this->key, 0, $this->key_size);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Static method alias for string encryption
     * @param string $string The string to encrypt
     * @return string The encrypted string
     */
    public static function enc($string) {
        $e = new self;
        return $e->encrypt_string($string);
    }

    /**
     * Static method alias for string decryption
     * @param string $enc_string The previously encrypted string
     * @return string The decrypted/original string
     */
    public static function dec($enc_string) {
        $e = new self;
        return $e->decrypt_string($enc_string);
    }

    /**
     * Encrypt a string
     * @param string $string - string to encrypt
     * @return string - encrypted string
     */
    function encrypt_string($string) {
        $enc = mcrypt_encrypt(
            $this->cipher,
            $this->key,
            $string,
            $this->mode,
            $this->iv
        );

        $enc = base64_encode($this->iv . $enc);
        /**
         * replace potentially illegal chars
         */
        $enc = strtr($enc, '+/=', '-_,');

        /**
         * remove unnecessary and ugly trailing commas
         */
        $enc = strrev($enc);
        if(substr($enc,0,1) == ',') $enc = substr($enc,1);
        if(substr($enc,0,1) == ',') $enc = substr($enc,1);
        $enc = strrev($enc);

        return $enc;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypt an encrypted string and return the original
     * @param string $s The string previously encrypted with this class
     * @return string The original unencrypted string
     */
    function decrypt_string($s) {

        $s  = strtr($s, '-_,', '+/=');
        $s  = base64_decode($s);
        $this->iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size($this->cipher, $this->mode);
        $this->iv = substr($s, 0, $this->iv_size);
        $data = substr($s, $this->iv_size);
        /**
         * supress warnings because they happen every time
         * IV parameter must be as long as the block size
         * yet this still works perfectly
         */
        $decrypted = @mcrypt_decrypt($this->cipher, $this->key, $data, $this->mode, $this->iv);

        return trim($decrypted);
    }

    /**
     * Serialize an object into an encrypted string
     * @throws Exception
     * @param object $object
     * @return string
     */
    function encrypt_object($object) {
        if(is_resource($object)) throw new Exception("Cannot encrypt objects of type 'resource'");
        $ser = serialize($object);
        $enc = base64_encode($ser);
        return $this->encrypt_string($enc);
    }

    /**
     * Unserialize an encrypted string back into an object
     * @param string $enc
     * @return object
     */
    function decrypt_object($enc) {
        $dec = $this->decrypt_string($enc);
        $unenc = base64_decode($dec);
        return unserialize($unenc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unserialize + unauthenticated encryption + using substr() with binary data + blowfish + using a password as an encryption key. This is a swiss army knife of security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski To be fair, Blowfish isn't a security weakness. Yes, it's a 64-bit block cipher, not recommended any longer by the author, and has a practical encryption limitation of 32GB, but there aren't any known vulnerabilities in Blowfish that make breaking its ciphertexts practical. :)

Comment: @AaronToponce That is totally fair.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski I just realized that the class comments suggest using this class with URLs, which I never do.  In fact, I don't use this class with any user-supplied data at all.  I'll update the post.  Thanks for the eyeballs.

Comment: @rmirabelle Finding vulnerabilities in crypto libraries is a hobby horse of mine. https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption and https://github.com/zendframework/zend-crypt provide great symmetric-key encryption.

Comment: @ScottArciszewski Thanks for sharing this! Will definitely check it out and am happy to learn more about this very 'cryptic' area of security!

Comment: @rmirabelle https://paragonie.com/blog/tag/cryptography might help too :)